# Get Minecraft server seed with location of structures?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

So I'm trying to figure out a way to get the seed from a Minecraft server using the location of existing structures, or possibly the way blocks are in a single un-modified chunk. This can be brute force, probably because it's the only thing that will possibly work.

I've seen previous posts where someone said they had made a tool to do it. Is it possible to get the seed using [this tool](https://github.com/altf4/untwister), perhaps?

Comment: Has something gone wrong with the world?  I'm pretty sure the seed is saved in the level.dat

Comment: Nothing is wrong with the world, I can't access level.dat, as I'm not operator, and I've read you can get the world seed using the location of generated structures.

Comment: So this is a duplicate, sorry. One of the answers in the thread says it wouldn't actually take as long as people think, and that he was working on a tool to get the seed, but I can't seem to find anything to do that, as I don't think he published the tool.

Comment: depending on your permissions you might be able to run "/seed" and it will just output the server seed right to you.

Comment: I don't think I can use _/seed_, as I'm not operator

Comment: However, I did find [this](https://hastebin.com/rotukuziga.c) bit of code, which might work. It's going to be really slow, but if I put in the location of existing slime chunks, it should calculate it.